# Error with con.open() with MS Access DB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

When reaching `con.open()`, I am getting an error.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim con As OleDbConnection
Dim strCon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\testDB.accdb"
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
con = New OleDbConnection(strCon)
con.Open()
MsgBox("con open")
con.Close()
MsgBox("con closed")

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please specify the error you are getting.

Comment: Is that really a valid connection string ***to*** open? Ensure the connection string is correct, which is mainly the issue for these types of exceptions

Comment: Without seeing the error message you are getting it is difficult to advise on a solution. Try looking [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007) in case there is a problem with your connection string e.g. missing username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the error it's difficult to tell but may be a permissions issue?

Right click the testDB.accdb file, `Properties`, `Security`, `Edit`, `Add`, type 'everyone', click `Check Names`, `Ok`, tick the `Full Control` checkbox when everyone is highlighted and then `Ok` twice more.